# Text and image in div - How to align correctly?

Tags: css

I have text and image inside a div and I want the text to be aligned at the top of the image, not the middle.

Here's how it looks: http://bitly.com/VSSoul

CSS:

```
.book1 {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.book2 {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.book1 img {
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

How do I make the text go to the top of the div, and not center relative of image?

Comment: `h4 { margin-top: 0; } .book1 { margin-bottom: 1em; }`? Also, I don't see any element in your HTML with a class of `.book2`.

Comment: thank you! if you submit your solution as an answer I will give you the correct answer as you were the first commenter and solved the problem for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually is aligned to the top.  The h4 tag has default margins, so setting:

```
h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
.book img {
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.book {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Demo JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/e636q/

Answer (score 0):

hear you go. add

```
h4 { margin-top: 0; }
.book1 {margin-bottom: 1.5em;}
```

the extra margin on .book1 helps with spacing the individual books apart